# Display Images (url) Inside Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I would like to display images (mostly jpg and png formats) **directly from their url link** inside a pandas dataframe. Imagine I already have the following dataframe:

```
id image_url
1  http://www.nstravel.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/germany-profile_6023_600x450.jpg
2  https://www.nh-hotels.com/multimedia/images/cityscape-of-berlin_retoque_600x458-tcm41-132903-32.jpg
3  https://www.scandichotels.com/imagevault/publishedmedia/8q33xlshjl4o9d5ftp3r/germany-berlin-berliner-dom-cathedral-in-the-eveni.jpg
```

**I would like to have the actual image displayed in another column (properly resized to fit).**

I am aware that I could do it differently, e.g. not using pandas and go with grids using matplotlib, but for ease of illustration and presentation I would prefer to show it within a table (dataframe).

I have found these solutions: [solution1](https://www.kaggle.com/stassl/displaying-inline-images-in-pandas-dataframe), [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365824/pandas-ipython-notebook-include-and-display-an-image-in-a-dataframe). These suggested solutions while seem very relevant but did not work for me. Even I tried with images from my local disk, but I get this using the solution2:

[image]

Python: 3.6.5, Pandas: 0.23.0, Jupyter: 4.4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually the solution2 worked; I just had to be a bit more patient. I am posting it here in case someone have difficulties, like me, getting this to work:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

def path_to_image_html(path):
    '''
     This function essentially convert the image url to 
     '<img src="'+ path + '"/>' format. And one can put any
     formatting adjustments to control the height, aspect ratio, size etc.
     within as in the below example. 
    '''

    return '<img src="'+ path + '" style=max-height:124px;"/>'

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(column_name_with_image_links=path_to_image_html)))
```

Note that *df* is your actual dataframe name, *column_name_with_image_links* is the column name that contains all image urls, and *path_to_image_html* is the above function.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the above solution with formatters it is also possible to create a column with HTML `img` tag directly in the DataFrame. Another important note is that long URLs can be eaten by a string shortener (contents get replaced by `...`). To avoid this one can use `pd.option_context()` with `display.max_colwidth` set an appropriate value.

The above mentioned is turned into something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

df['img_html'] = df['column_name_with_image_links']\
    .str.replace(
        '(.*)', 
        '<img src="\\1" style="max-height:124px;"></img>'
    )
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 10000):
    HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

Comment: TIL: `pd.option_context`!! FTW