# visualize images inside the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, image

I use python 3.7.3 and I run this code on Jupyter Notebook .

I have a column named 'image' in my Dataframe named df that contains Url of images I wanna visualize inside the df.

I saw some answers and I tried to use this code:

```py
from IPython.display import Image, HTML

def path_to_image_html(path):

    return '<img src="'+ path + '" style=max-height:124px;"/>'

HTML(df.to_html(escape=False ,formatters=dict(image=path_to_image_html)))
```

However, I get this result instead:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I get the images using this code or any other code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Images (url) Inside Pandas Dataframe](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38083/display-images-url-inside-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @TwinPenguins as you see I used the same code but it didn't work for me, I still don't know why

Comment: You are right. It is not reproducible. I just reopened it again. I will have a look too. I think some sort of HTML settings need to be changed.

Comment: I would move this question in stackoverflow. Here it is more about Data Science.

Comment: I will do that, thanks !